# hash map function error

Tags: c++, c, hash, dictionary

I tried to make a hash function which hashes according to the formula given below and resolves collisions by another function `23*j+j*j+hash`. I don't want to insert into the table if it has to check for more than 20 collisions, i.e it returns `-1`. But there is some error as for input when there are more than 20 elements of same hash value. I am not able to figure it out. Plese help??

```
int hashi(string key)
{
    int ans =0,oo,i;
    int len = key.length();
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        ans += ((int)key[i]*(i+1));
    }

    ans = (ans*19)%101;

    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        oo = 23*i + i*i + ans;
        oo = oo%101;
        if(m[oo] == key)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(m[oo] == "")
        {
            return oo;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question, please rephrase

Comment: Please post a simple compiling example.

Comment: "But there is some error as for input when there are more than 20 elements of same hash value. I am not able to figure it out." - that's impenetrable.  `oo` is always between 0 and 100, so that's an absolutely maximum for the number of keys you can get into `m`, but you're likely to start getting 20 collisions earlier than that... maybe at something like 70 or 80% capacity, but a lot depends on the keys.

Comment: i will give you the problem statement

Comment: When performing  insert define the following function: 
integer Hash(string key),
which for a string key= a1...an returns the value:
     Hash(key)=h(key) mod 101, where 
     h(key)=19 *(ASCII(a1)*1+...+ASCII(an)*n).

Resolve collisions using the open addressing method, i.e. try to insert the key into the table at the first free position:
     (Hash(key)+j2+23*j) mod 101, for j=1,...,19.
 After examining of at least 20 table entries, we assume that the insert operation cannot be performed.

Comment: what i mean saying id that the problem is when i have many collisions .

Comment: for eg if i give 20 values of the same hash value the function gives me absurd results and with 5 values of same hash value it gives me correct result.